# Why does my code keep asking me for quarters 4 times?

Tags: python, function, input

I have this homework assignment and I'm not suppose to change this part of the code

```
def main():

    pennies = get_input("Enter pennies : ")
    nickels = get_input("Enter nickels : ")
    dimes = get_input("Enter dimes : ")
    quarters = get_input("Enter quarters : ")

    print("You entered : ")
    print("\tPennies  : " , pennies)
    print("\tNickels  : " , nickels)
    print("\tDimes    : " , dimes)
    print("\tQuarters : " , quarters)

    total_value = get_total(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)
    dollars, cents = get_left_over_cents(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)
    left_over_cents = get_left_over_cents(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)
    print("Total = $", format(total_value,".02f"), sep="")
    print('You have', dollars, "dollars and", cents, "cent(s)")
```

This is my code for the assignment that I've done

```
def main():
    pennies = get_input("Enter pennies : ")
    nickels = get_input("Enter nickels : ")
    dimes = get_input("Enter dimes : ")
    quarters = get_input("Enter quarters : ")

    print("You entered : ")
    print("\tPennies  : " , pennies)
    print("\tNickels  : " , nickels)
    print("\tDimes    : " , dimes)
    print("\tQuarters : " , quarters)

    total_value = get_total(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)
    dollars, cents = get_left_over_cents(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)
    left_over_cents = get_left_over_cents(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)
    print("Total = $", format(total_value,".02f"), sep="")
    print('You have', dollars, "dollars and", cents, "cent(s)")

def get_input(pennies):
    pennies = input("Enter Pennies: ")
    while int(pennies) < 0:
        print("Error: money cannot be negative")
        pennies = int(input("Enter correct amount of pennies: "))
    return pennies

def get_input(nickels):
    nickels = input("Enter nickels: ")
    while int(nickels) < 0:
        print("Error: money cannot be negative")
        nickels = int(input("Enter correct amount of nickels: "))
    return nickels

def get_input(dimes):
    dimes = input("Enter dimes: ")
    while int(dimes) < 0:
        print("Error: money cannot be negative")
        dimes = int(input("Enter correct amount of dimes: "))
    return dimes

def get_input(quarters):
    quarters = input("Enter quarters: ")
    while int(quarters) < 0:
        print("Error: money cannot be negative")
        quarters = int(input("Enter correct amount of quarters: "))
    return quarters

def get_total(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters):
    amount_pennies = (int(pennies) * .01)
    amount_nickels = (int(nickels) * .05)
    amount_dimes = (int(dimes) * .10)
    amount_quarters = (int(quarters) * .25)
    return amount_pennies + amount_nickels + amount_dimes + amount_quarters

def get_left_over_cents(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters):
    total = int(pennies) + 5*int(nickels) + 10*int(dimes) + 25*int(quarters)
    return total // 100, total % 100

main()
```

But everytime I run the code, it tells me to enter quarters 4 times. But I want it to say enter pennies, enter nickels, and so forth. Can someone help me? I'm really confused on how to make it do that without changing that core code

Comment: I believe you're trying to do method overload and that doesn't exist in python.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Maybe it should just get a job? Seriously, learn to use the debugger and these mysteries will answer them selves for you https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Comment: The hint is in the part of the code you're not supposed to change. There is only one function called get_input that returns four different types of coins, not four separate functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You keep redefining your `get_input` function.  Each time you do so, the old `get_input` function is overshadowed and becomes no longer available.  So, in the end, you only have the `get_input` you made for quarters.

You need to rename your functions so that each has a unique name that will not overshadow another function.  Why not do something like:

```
def get_pennies(...):
    ...

def get_nickels(...):
    ...

def get_dimes(...):
    ...

def get_quarters(...):
    ...
```

Or, even better, make a single function that can handle all coin types.  A (basic) example is below:

```
def get_coin(coin_type):
    amount = int(input("Enter " + coin_type + ": "))  # BTW, you forgot to call int() up here before.
    while amount < 0:
        print("Error: money cannot be negative")
        amount = int(input("Enter correct amount of " + coin_type + ": "))
    return amount
```

You would then call this function as:

```
pennies = get_coin('pennies')
nickels = get_coin('nickels')
...
```

Comment: +1, but ugh, don't rename the functions! They are so repetitive and should be merged into a single function that handles all kinds of coins.

Comment: Since he can't change the top part of the code, I don't think renaming is an option.

Comment: Hmm.  That would be much better.  I'll show the OP an example.

Comment: I did that and then my teacher told me to not change anything up there. I named them get_input1, 2, 3, 4 and then the code worked perfect, but then she tells me that I cant change that. Is there any other way to do that without messing with that?

Comment: @linus: Why not? The function `def get_input(string):` could check `if "pennies" in string:` and act accordingly.

Comment: fair enough.. i didn't think of that, but i would still recommend just having one simple function that handles all the coins.

Comment: Thank you. I never thought about using just one get_input to get all the coins. I just hope she doesn't tell me I can't do that either. That'll really bum me out, haha

Comment: @steveverwey - Having one function to do the job is the correct approach.  Any time you need to copy/paste blocks of code inside a source file, it means your design needs reworking.  I'd be surprised if your teacher forced you to write such redundant code.

Answer (score 4):

As [iCodez explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26898163/908494), every time you write `def get_input(dimes):` or `def get_input(quarters):`, you're just creating a new definition for the function `get_input`, and hiding the old one. The fact that the parameter has a different name doesn't mean anything. (How could it? When you write `pennies = get_input("Enter pennies : ")`, how would Python know that you want to call `get_input(pennies)` instead of `get_input(quarters)`?)

You can fix this by giving each one a unique name (`get_pennies`, `get_nickels`, etc.), and calling them by the unique names.

Also, notice that you're not actually *using* the argument `pennies` or `nickels` or whatever. You're taking a prompt string, and doing nothing with it.

And that's important, because it means you can refactor them all into one function. If you look at the implementations you've written, they're already almost identical; the only difference is in the prompt strings you print out. And you're already getting a different prompt string with each call. So, why not just use it?

```
def get_input(prompt):
    number = input(prompt)
    while int(number) < 0:
        print("Error: money cannot be negative")
        number = int(input(prompt))
    return number
```

Now, `pennies = get_input("Enter pennies : ")` will ask you for pennies, `nickels = get_input("Enter nickels : ")` will ask you for nickels, etc.

---

As a side note, there's a serious bug in all four of your implementations (and in my merged version(). If your first input is non-negative, the function will return the string, like `"3"`; if that one is negative, but a later one is not, the function will return the integer value, like `5`. You probably want to make the first `number = …` and the second one identical.